# How to float left content and fix right content?

Tags: html, css, header, fixed

I am working on a structure to have a top navigation fixed, a left nav to be scrollable and a right nav to be fixed.

I have created a fiddle here. just need help with the css.

http://jsfiddle.net/PxbX9/

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    background:red;
    width:700px;
    height:30px;
}
#left-block {
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    background:blue;
    height:1000px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
#right-block {
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    height:1000px;
    background:pink;
    margin-top:30px;
    .fixed-block {
        postion:fixed;
        height:1000px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by restructuring your `CSS` to this:

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    background:red;
    width:700px;
    height:30px;
}
#left-block {
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    background:blue;
    height:1000px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
#right-block {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    width:350px;
    height:1000px;
    background:pink;
    margin-top:30px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

I've *only* made `CSS` changes to the `#right-block` selector.

1. Removed the class `.fixed-block`, which had a typo in the form of `postion` (should be `position`).
2. `position: fixed;` has been added to the `#right-block` selector.
3. `display: inline-block;` and `float: right;` have been added also.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PxbX9/1/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/CTJwQ/1/)

### Pure CSS solution, Very Dynamic, Totally responsive.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
    </div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <div class="RightContent">
            </div>
            <div class="LeftContent">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .Container
{
    height: 100%;
}
    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
.HeightTaker
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .HeightTaker:after
    {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
.Wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.Header
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #bf5b5b;
}
.Wrapper > div
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.LeftContent
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #90adc1;
}
.RightContent
{
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #77578a;
}
```